# Why does AWS ECS have a limit of 10240 CPU units?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ecs

I have a script that uses 60 cores.  So when I run it on a c518XLarge EC2, it uses most of the 72 cores (e.g. if I run top I see numbers around 90%).  When I created a docker job on AWS ECS, it only used about 12%.  Messing with the CPU limit didn't help and only allowed a max of 10.  Why is this limit imposed, what is its purpose, and how do I get around this?

Comment: Usually contacting support will help to increase the limit. Even if I run AWS, I cannot open sea of cores just like that to end consumer, without understanding to see is there really a need for it or verify if you are really missing to use any other features of cloud that can scale.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I am facing a similar issue. Thanks